# Need help with this proof ∀x ∈ R[∃y ∈ R(x + y = yx) ↔ x ≠ 1]

Tags: proof-verification

Having a hard time proving this one.  I can prove this with a contradiction in the (→) direction but I'm stuck on how to prove
this in the (←) direction where x ≠ 1 is the given and ∀x ∈ R[∃y ∈ R(x + y = yx)] is the goal.  Any help is MUCH appreciated!

∀x ∈ R[∃y ∈ R(x + y = yx) ↔ x ≠ 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof where we prove both directions at the same time. Let's treat this as a simplification problem: we are asked to simplify $\;\exists y \left ( x + y = yx \right )\;$.  The easiest way to do that, is to rewrite $\;x + y = yx\;$ to something of the form $\;y = \ldots\;$.

(Note that I'm leaving out $\;{}\in R\;$ throughout, to reduce visual clutter.)$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\then}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

---

So we calculate as follows, for any $\;x\;$:
$$\calc
    \exists y \left ( x + y = yx \right )
\op\equiv\hint{arithmetic -- to bring all $\;y\;$'s to the same side}
    \exists y \left ( yx - y = x \right )
\op\equiv\hint{arithmetic -- to have a single $\;y\;$}
    \exists y \left ( y(x - 1) = x \right )
\op\equiv\hint{divide by $\;x-1\;$, splitting off special case $\;x-1=0\;$}
    \exists y \left ( \left ( x = 1 \;\land\; y \times 0 = 1 \right )\;\lor\; \left ( x \not= 1 \;\land\; y = \frac x {x-1} \right ) \right )
\op\equiv\hint{LHS of $\;\lor\;$ is false}
    \exists y \left ( x \not= 1 \;\land\; y = \frac x {x-1} \right )
\op\equiv\hint{one-point rule for $\;\exists\;$}
    x \not= 1
\endcalc$$

---

The one-point rule for $\;\exists\;$ is the law of logic which says that
$$
\exists y \left (y = E \land P(y) \right ) \;\equiv\; P(E)
$$
where $\;E\;$ does not contain $\;y\;$: if $\;y\;$ and $\;E\;$ are equal, then we can just substitute $\;E\;$ for $\;y\;$.  There are many such laws; see, e.g., [another answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/657613/11994).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  How we get to y = x/x-1 from y+x = yx.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can write out the solution explicitly, $y=x(x-1)^{-1}$ which of course is only defined if $x \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

In the reverse direction we are given $x$ such that $x\neq 1$ and asked to find y so that the equation holds. Note that $$x+y=yx\iff x=y(x-1).$$ Since $x\neq 1$ we can take $y=\dfrac{x}{x-1}$.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been having more trouble with the algebra than the logic to perform the actual proof.  I knew I had to define y in terms of x but couldn't figure out that it was x/x-1.  You wouldn't happen to know of any good algebra books/resources?  I'm learning this stuff on my own and things like this have been kicking my butt :)

Comment: Google Paul Lamar's algebra notes.